# Need to change system locale on Windows 2012 R2 from en-US to en-GB

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, localization

When I start an Aws Ec2 Windows 2012 R2 instance it always comes with a default en-US locale.

However I need to change two of the existing instances to be en-GB as if they were installed like that in the first place.  Which is to say I need to change the locale to en-GB for all users including system users like Network Service or Local Service.

Is there a way to do this?

I have tried in powershell Set-WinSystemLocale en-GB but even though I get no error it does nothing even after a reboot.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Should have put above was really hoping to be able to do this without a registry hack.  If I have to I guess I have to.

Answer (score 3):

This [set of instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7) I found for Windows 7 on windows.microsoft.com *seems* to work:

1. Open **Region and Language** by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **Clock, Language, and Region**, and then clicking **Region and Language**.
2. Click the **Administrative** tab, and then, under **Language for non-Unicode programs**, click **Change system locale**. If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
3. Select the language, and then click **OK**.
4. To restart your computer, click **Restart now**.

Answer (score -2):

Try to copy locale settings from current user registry to the .DEFAULT key or use an [IntlCfg](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722068%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) utility.

Comment: Link doesn't work. And I could do with some more verbose instructions not knowing where to look in the registry.